# C++ , Inheritance for variable which share the same purpose but different datatype

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Base class

```cpp
class SudokuGenerator {  
    protected: // protected is accessible by derived class
        DatabaseConnection DB;
    public:
        virtual void generate() = 0; //pure virtual function that need to be implemented in derived class
        virtual void getSuccessTask() = 0;
        virtual void getFailTask() = 0;
};
```

4 derived class

```cpp
class SudokuGenerator_SingleThread : SudokuGenerator { 
    private:
        atomic<int> successTask;
        atomic<int> failTask;
    public: 
        void generate() override;
        void getSuccessTask() override;
        void getFailTask() override;
};
```

```cpp
class SudokuGenerator_MultiThread_ATOMIC : SudokuGenerator { 
    private:
        int successTask;
        int failTask;
    public:
        void generate() override;
        void getSuccessTask() override;
        void getFailTask()override;
};
```

```cpp
class SudokuGenerator_MultiThread_MUTEX : SudokuGenerator { 
    private:
        int successTask;
        int failTask;
    public:
        void generate() override;
        void getSuccessTask() override;
        void getFailTask() override;
};
```

```cpp
class SudokuGenerator_MultiThread_INT : SudokuGenerator { 
    private:
        int successTask;
        int failTask;
    public:
        void generate() override;
        void getSuccessTask() override;
        void getFailTask() override;
};
```

I have a base class which generate sudoku, and from my derived class, there are private variable for counting success and fail task (insertion to database). As I know there are not anything call **Virtual Variable** in C++, therefore I have following question.

1. As the successTask and fail Task is different datatype for the 4 derived function, is there a way to include these variable to the base class, if not, is there anyway to improve my code in this area.
2. I know there is not any abstract class in C++, is there a way that I could implement SudokuGenerator that it is invalid to declare a SudokuGenerator object (baseclass)

Comment: Why can't you split the concerns here into the base class vs. some kind of runner that can be *composed* into the instance?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, what do you mean by some kind of runner that can be composed into the instance

Comment: Do you need these to be dispatched virtually, or will you always know the type of the implementation at compile-time? If the latter, you can parameterize `SudokuGenerator` as `SudokuGenerator<T>` and then inherit it as `SudokuGenerator_SingleThread : SudokuGenerator<atomic<int>>` for instance. The four subclasses don't inherit from a common superclass anymore, but if you know all of the types at compile-time, then you can do everything in templates anyway.

Comment: Whoever told you that "there is not any abstract class in C++" gave you wrong information. You happened to have created an abstract class, already, and there's nothing wrong with it. Looks like you misunderstood something, this question is moot.